# Is Ted Hickman right that he should've won his election in 2018?

Tags: united-states, election, local-government, california, lgbt+

Ted Hickman was the Vice-Mayor of Dixon, California, who prior to election penned a column insulting homosexuals and calling for a "Straight Pride month". After he lost his election he said [this](https://archive.ph/MNQDr):

> I only responded back to one sissy cyber bully telling him (I guess it was a him, he used a straight man’s name) to check his math so I made it simpler for him/her/them: This is a city of about 20,000 of which only about 5,000 voted; (shameful I know) and in my district only a little over 1,000 voted with about 700 for Ernst and 300 for me… hardly a “get out of town edict”.  **Those in the know said had the whole city been able to vote things would have ended differently. The truth be known (this is not sour grapes) Ernest was bought and paid for the same as Scott Pederson, with their public sworn allegiance to the LGB-WTF  and its causes furthering their abnormal ( as compared to our normal mom, pop, kids the natural way) lifestyle. Look at their public documented showing where their campaign funds came from.**

Why was turnout so low? Would there really have been a change?

Comment: On a quick google search "Across the U.S., only 15 to 27 percent of eligible voters cast a ballot in their local election." So the turnout was actually pretty high here.

Comment: Ah, now that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

> should've won his election

He, and maybe you too, might be expressing [some seriously wishful thinking](https://www.sacbee.com/news/politics-government/election/local-election/article221282330.html):

> Ted Hickman was defeated for Dixon City Council District 2 by the city’s planning commissioner, Jim Ernest, who picked up **72 percent** of the vote with all ballots counted.

... 72% is not a small margin and just because he is embarking on another disastrous rant does not make it any more than a sore loser's personal opinion about losing an election.

For fairly obvious reasons, one might add. I mean, in 2022, who the **** writes "sissy" in a political context??? Googling *Dixon california elections Ted Hickman* does not give one the impression that it was a very surprising outcome.

In addition, while it is not a direct match, and while Solano County does have a relatively high - for CA- % of Reps, the results of 2020 POTUS make one think that his original anti-gay rant wasn't the cleverest political move - whatever the, hopefully small, proportion of Republican voters would approve of it, there wasn't that big a pool of Republican voters for poor Ted to work with.

[63% Biden, 33% Trump](https://www.thereporter.com/2020-general-election-results-for-solano-county/)

To add to this, from Fizz's comment, that his main argument, blaming a low turnout for his ousting, falls apart when one realizes that low turnouts are business as usual for that type of elections.

Have you done **any** research before asking this question?  What info have you found that supports Ted's claims?  Can you link to it?

Comment: I never said I agreed with him. But it's always good to fact check,